# Loading Tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to load package `library(tidyverse)` but the following error is happening:

`Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’: .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details: call: NULL error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): namespace ‘cli’ 3.5.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.6.1 is required`

and i can not update `cli`

Plese help me with this...

Thank you!

Solve package loading

Comment: restart your session and install the tidyverse again

Comment: Thanks! 
I had to uninstall "cli" and "tidyverse" and load two package again. Also, reinstall R and Rstudio and it works.